# Which objects have the EventTarget interface?

Tags: javascript, events, addeventlistener

according to MDN
*Element, and its children, as well as Document and Window*
are EventTargets.
What does *its children* mean?
Since I can't add events to text nodes, right?
Thanks and Greetings

Comment: That's actually a great question. It means that event bubbling will be passed to the children/parent or stopped with `event.stopPropagation`. It's not a reference to the DOMElement children, its a reference to the Event **Listener** tree and its parent or children. You can find more information here: https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing

Comment: "_I can't add events to text nodes_" [Actually you can](https://jsfiddle.net/oLdsub0t/).

Comment: _"What does its children mean?"_ - Anything that inherits from `Element`

Comment: @Teemu ,thanks for the example. Can you explain why it works with dispatchEvent and not in the "normal" way. Is it because of the synchronous way?

Comment: Not exactly, it's just that browser UI doesn't listen events on textnode level, it's listening elements only. The example just shows, that it's possible to attach an event to any object inheriting from EventTarget. I'm not sure if this is even [useful or practical](https://jsfiddle.net/9gkyeuw2/), but a nice detail in event behavior. There might be some practical use-cases, specifically when working with jQuery, which makes a lot of use of event dispatching (all events are bubbling in jQuery event model, even those which are not bubbling natively).

Comment: Even [more weird example](https://jsfiddle.net/9gkyeuw2/1/), hence the answer to your question in the title is: every object inheriting from [EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) has the EventTarget interface, that is almost any object in the DOM tree, and also some global objects, like XMLHttpRequest. And as you can see in the last linked example, any custom object inheriting EventTarget too.